# How to print certain classes only when I using ctrl+p for print

Tags: css, wordpress, printing, media

I want on the WP page with ctrl+p print only some classes and not the whole page. So can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unsure how free you are with WordPress, but, if you are able to implement your own CSS (since you used it as a tag), you can use a media query to exclude/include classes when the user prints the page. `@media print` targets the print style of the page.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>test.html</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <p class="c1">class 1</p>
    <p class="c2">class 2</p>
    <p class="c3">class 3</p>
</body>
</html>
```

```css
@media print {
    .c2 {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Web View:

[image: web page saying class 1, 2, and 3 on 3 separate lines]

Print View:

[image: web page saying class 1 and 3 on 2 separate lines]

Comment: Thank you. As I understood I need to hide all classes which I don't want to pirn right?

Comment: @S.Len Welcome :) That's the most straight-forward way I can think to do it, yes.

Answer (score -1):

-Clicking the Print button on the toolbar instantly prints the web page. To work the Print dialog box, choose Print from the Print button’s menu or press Ctrl+P.

-A single web page is often output to several printed pages.

-To print only part of a web page, select the part you want by using the mouse. Then press Ctrl+P and, in the Print dialog box, choose Selection. Click the Print button to print only the selected portion of the web page.

-Only one part of a web page can be selected at a time.

-Sometimes, text fails to show up when you select the Shrink to Fit option. It’s a “feature” of the web page. Simply choose another size from the Change Print Size menu.

-You can print an image on a web page by right-clicking the image and choosing Print Picture from the shortcut menu. This trick comes in handy when the image doesn’t print with the rest of the web page.

Comment: Thank you, but I need the users to print only one part of a web page..  it is not only for me..